# Issue with GLEW initialization causing program to not output

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glfw, glew

I'm encountering a problem while trying to use the GLEW library for my basic OpenGL program, which is written using GLFW (glfw3.h). Everything compiles without errors, but as soon as I call glewInit(), I don't get any output at all, including any cout statements, neither before nor after the initialization. However, when I remove the glewInit() call, everything works as expected.

I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC 1 

#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    //INFECTED LINE OF CODE - START
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err=glewInit();
    if(err!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
        std::cout<<"glewInit failed, aborting."<<std::endl;
    }
     //INFECTED LINE OF CODE - END

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    glEnd();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I've included GLEW and GLFW correctly, and there are no compilation errors. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Thanks for your help!

//EDIT#1
Tried using:

```
(...)
 glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err=glewInit();
    std::cout<<glewGetErrorString(err);
    glewGetErrorString(err);
    if(err!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
        std::cout<<glewGetErrorString(err);
        glewGetErrorString(err);
        std::cout<<"glewInit failed, aborting."<<std::endl;
    }
(...)
```

and still [No output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Z6g.png)

When I comment out the infected lines of code and leave only this line:

```
std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

I'm getting the output:

```
4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7637
```

//EDIT#2
debugger output:
[dbg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN5IH.png)

Comment: can you print the glew error with glewGetErrorString(err) ?

Comment: Check the #Edit1. Tried it and still got no output.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: It appears that I'm facing an unusual issue where I'm getting undefined reference errors for everything, but, as mentioned earlier, the code works without any issues when the "infected" lines are removed. Maybe here's the problem. How can i make it work? I'm using cmake to build the whole project.

Comment: std::cout<<glewGetErrorString(err) i mean

Comment: The debugger output says it clearly: "undefined reference to...". This means you lack linking with the required libraries (including headers is not enough). See [glfw libs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link) and [glew libs](https://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html). Perhaps you want to add glew code to your project instead of compiling it separately. And don't forget to add GL library (e.g. opengl32.dll for Windows or GL.so for Linux)

Comment: I heard about some possible conflicts between GLFW and loading libraries. Maybe you could try to add `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` before to include GLFW headers ? You also need to define GLFW_DLL on Windows when using the GLFW DLL. See [GLFW website](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call OpenGL functions like `glGetString` before `glewInit`. `glewInit()` is responsible for loading these functions dynamically from GPU driver's DLL.

If you do, you are likely getting segfault because `glGetString` is just a macro hiding uninitialized (at that moment) function pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I removed the line of code you mentioned, and I still don't see any output.

Comment: @veltronic Then please use a debugger to see what exactly crashes your application.

Comment: @veltronic you don't need remove but to move the line getting the OpenGL version, placing it after glew initialization.